# If exists update the XML column or insert into new row in reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

If exists data into parent table then update the child table on XML column based on the reference id, other wise insert into row.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
 PersonId INT CONSTRAINT PK_Person_PersonId PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(50),
 SubMittedDate DATETIME,
 SubmittedBy INT,
 RejectedDate DATETIME,
 RejectedBy INT
)

INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1, 'Sai', GETDATE(),1,null,null)

CREATE TABLE PersonXML
(
 PersonXMLId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_PersonXML_PersonId PRIMARY KEY,
 PersonId INT CONSTRAINT FK_PersonXML_Person FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(PersonId),
 Name VARCHAR(50),
 PersonHistory XML
)

INSERT INTO PersonXML(PersonId,Name,PersonHistory )
SELECT PersonId
      ,Name
      ,(SELECT PersonId             
            ,Name
            ,SubMittedDate
            ,SubmittedBy
            ,ISNULL(RejectedDate,0) AS RejectedDate
            ,ISNULL(RejectedBy, 0)  AS RejectedBy
            FROM Person FOR XML PATH('PersonHistory') )
FROM Person 

SELECT * FROM Person
SELECT * FROM  PersonXML
```

Whenever i Update Person Table in RejectedDate, RejectedBy Column then those changes has to reflect in PersonXML table on PersonHistory column automatically could anyone please find me way to achieve it.

```
UPDATE Person SET RejectedDate = GETDATE(), RejectedBy= 100 WHERE PersonId = 1
```

Comment: For the PersonXML table, check the MERGE command.  It's designed specifically for this, with a built in case for inserting a record if no matching record was found, or to update.  As for coupling the two commands, either write it into the procedure, or implement a trigger on the Person table.  Depends on what you prefer.

Comment: I am new to XML can u provide the URL for MERGE command to XML, the reference column is Person and PersonXML table is PersonId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PersonId int,@RejectedDate datetime,@RejectedBy int            
SET @PersonId=1
SET @RejectedDate=Getdate()+1
SET @RejectedBy=105
CREATE TABLE Person
(
 PersonId INT CONSTRAINT PK_Person_PersonId PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(50),
 SubMittedDate DATETIME,
 SubmittedBy INT,
 RejectedDate DATETIME,
 RejectedBy INT
)

INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1, 'Sai', GETDATE(),1,null,null)

CREATE TABLE PersonXML
(
 PersonXMLId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_PersonXML_PersonId PRIMARY KEY,
 PersonId INT CONSTRAINT FK_PersonXML_Person FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(PersonId),
 Name VARCHAR(50),
 PersonHistory XML
)

INSERT INTO PersonXML(PersonId,Name,PersonHistory )
SELECT PersonId
      ,Name
      ,(SELECT PersonId             
            ,Name
            ,SubMittedDate
            ,SubmittedBy
            ,ISNULL(RejectedDate,0) AS RejectedDate
            ,ISNULL(RejectedBy, 0)  AS RejectedBy
            FROM Person FOR XML PATH('PersonHistory') )
FROM Person 

IF Exists(SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonId=@PersonId)  
BEGIN  
 UPDATE Person  
SET  
 RejectedDate =@RejectedDate ,RejectedBy=@RejectedBy
WHERE PersonId=@PersonId  
    UPDATE PersonXML  
    SET PersonHistory= 
    (SELECT PersonId             
            ,Name
            ,SubMittedDate
            ,SubmittedBy
            ,ISNULL(RejectedDate,@RejectedDate) AS RejectedDate
            ,ISNULL(RejectedBy,@RejectedBy)  AS RejectedBy
            FROM Person FOR XML PATH('PersonHistory')  )WHERE PersonId=@PersonId 
END
   ELSE  
     BEGIN  
          INSERT INTO Person 
          Select @PersonId,'', GETDATE(),1,@RejectedDate,@RejectedBy

     END  
SELECT * FROM Person
SELECT * FROM  PersonXML
```

Comment: Hope this will help you out

Comment: I need to update the PersonHistory XML column on PersonXML table, those are XML attributes.

Comment: you can rate me also for your help